# jQuery popup dialog when user loading images

Tags: jquery

Basically I want a modal windows popup with loading indicator when a user first come to the site and then it will disappear after all the images are loaded. Any plugin or way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with **[jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/home)**.

**[load the images](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/)**

**[dialog window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default)** is an overlay positioned within the viewport and is protected from page content (like select elements) shining through with an iframe. It has a title bar and a content area, and can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon by default.

**[The progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/)** is designed to simply display the current % complete for a process. The bar is coded to be flexibly sized through CSS and will scale to fit inside it's parent container by default.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery > jQueryUI

[Check this out.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)